# Replace the nth field of every mth line using awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

For a file that contains entries similar to as follows:

```
foo  1  6  0
fam  5  11  3
wam  7  23  8
woo  2  8  4
kaz  6  4  9
faz  5  8  8
```

How would you replace the nth field of *every* mth line with the same element using bash or awk?

For example, if *n = 1* and *m = 3* and the element = `wot`, the output would be:

```
foo  1  6  0
fam  5  11  3
wot  7  23  8
woo  2  8  4
kaz  6  4  9
wot  5  8  8
```

I understand you can call / print every mth line using e.g.

```
awk 'NR%7==0' file
```

So far I have tried to keep this in memory but to no avail... I need to keep the rest of the file as well.

I would prefer answers using bash or awk, but sed solutions would also be helpful. I'm a beginner in all three. Please explain your solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v m=3 -v n=1 -v el='wot' 'NR % m == 0 { $n = el } 1' file
```

Note, however, that the inter-field whitespace is not guaranteed to be preserved as-is, because `awk` splits a line into fields by any run of whitespace; as written, the output fields of modified lines will be separated by a *single space*.
If your input fields are *consistently* separated by *2 spaces*, however, you can effectively preserve the input whitespace by adding `-F'  ' -v OFS='  '` to the `awk` invocation.

- `-v m=3 -v n=1 -v el='wot'` defines Awk variables `m`, `n`, and `el`
- `NR % m == 0` is a *pattern* (condition) that evaluates to true for every m-th line.

  - `{ $n = el }` is the associated *action* that replaces the nth field of the input line with variable `el`, causing the line to be *rebuilt*, implicitly using `OFS`, the output-field separator, which defaults to a space.
- `1` is a common Awk shorthand for printing the (possibly modified) input line at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Great little exercise. While I would probably lean toward an `awk` solution, in bash you can also rely on *parameter expansion with substring replacement* to replace the *nth* field of every *mth* line. Essentially, you can read every line, preserving whitespace, then check your line count, e.g. if `c` is your line counter and `m` your variable for `mth` line, you could use:

```
    if (( $((c % m )) == 0))    ## test for mth line
```

If the line is a replacement line, you can read each word into an array after restoring default word-splitting and then use your array element index `n-1` to provide the replacement (e.g. `${line/find/replace}` with `${line/"${array[$((n-1))]}"/replace}`).

If it isn't a replacement line, simply output the line unchanged. A short example could be similar to the following (to which you can add additional validations as required)

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -n "$1" -a -r "$1" ] || {    ## filename given an readable
    printf "error: insufficient or unreadable input.\n"
    exit 1
}

n=${2:-1}       ## variables with default n=1, m=3, e=wot
m=${3:-3}
e=${4:-wot}
c=1             ## line count

while IFS= read -r line; do    
    if (( $((c % m )) == 0))    ## test for mth line
    then
        IFS=$' \t\n'
        a=( $line )             ## split into array
        IFS=
        echo "${line/"${a[$((n-1))]}"/$e}"  ## nth replaced with e
    else
        echo "$line"   ## otherwise just output line
    fi
    ((c++))         ## advance counter
done <"$1"
```

**Example Use/Output**

`n=1`, `m=3`, `e=wot`

```
$ bash replmn.sh dat/repl.txt
foo  1  6  0
fam  5  11  3
wot  7  23  8
woo  2  8  4
kaz  6  4  9
wot  5  8  8
```

`n=1`, `m=2`, `e=baz`

```
$ bash replmn.sh dat/repl.txt 1 2 baz
foo  1  6  0
baz  5  11  3
wam  7  23  8
baz  2  8  4
kaz  6  4  9
baz  5  8  8
```

`n=3`, `m=2`, `e=99`

```
$ bash replmn.sh dat/repl.txt 3 2 99
foo  1  6  0
fam  5  99  3
wam  7  23  8
woo  2  99  4
kaz  6  4  9
faz  5  99  8
```

An `awk` solution is shorter (and avoids problems with duplicate occurrences of the replacement string in `$line`), but both would need similar validation of field existence, etc.. Learn from both and let me know if you have any questions.